# shopware REST API orders list

Tags: api, orders, shopware

I want to collect all orders from Shopware by the REST API with all the information same as in the API request like this:

```
$client->get('orders/2002?useNumberAsId=true');
```

But if you use `$client->get('orders');` you get all the orders but missing the articles and customer information.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate all orders you got by $client->get('orders'); an make an api call for each order, to get full order information.
Or you can implement your own api endpoint (to get full order information with one query).